# How to display guitar tablature on screen?

Tags: java, signal-processing, guitar

I'm developing a system that extracts pitch from an audio track and displays it on a guitar tablature. I figured out there are many DSP libraries to for the pitch extraction part. 
ASCII tab is something i read about how guitar tablature is displayed but I'm not too sure how to do this. Elaborate on this method? And can anyone suggest more methods to do this like built in libraries for Java that can visualize guitar tablature?

Edit - I saw a project which uses a guitar tab editor to display guitar tablature. Not sure how this works

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if you play guitar yourself, but thinking about the fact that the same note can be played in up to 4 different places on the fretboard should make it clear that it's not that simple. I think that automatic tabulature layout out is not impossible but next to, as it is not sufficient to display the notes but also to bear the fingering in mind...

Comment: Yes i play guitar and i'm aware of the fact that the same note can be played at 4 different places and this will be a major problem when extracting the pitch. The question is how can i display the tablature once extracting pitch/frequency

Comment: Why have you chosen Java? Have you thought about using HTML5 canvas and Javascript? I think it may be more portable.

Comment: @Rodrigo point noted.  i was actually thinking of using c++ because of its machine level memory management efficiency and when it comes to FFT and DSP c++ is the best but i'm restricted with time and i'm thinking of creating my own simple DSP.

Comment: I get your point. So probably C is better than C++. Or even Assembler, if you have the guts for it. Look here: http://www.micosyen.com/aboutus.php. This guy developed a 44 kB mp3 player for windows (http://www.micosyen.com/mp3.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a listing of guitar tablature programs:

http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/apps/categories/for_guitarists_only see this

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_guitar_tablature_software)

you have to find one that has a commandline interface because then you can use the program directly if it is supported by your OS (operating system).
For sure  eTktab and Tux Guitar are opensource. Look in the source code (obey the license !) and maybe use parts of it for your program.
If you use their code in commercial applications you have to pay license fees else it would be nice if you donate for the project.

Comment: I would go with TuxGuitar, as it is written in Java which the OP mentions.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII format what you should try.

i would recommend reading the documentations for power-tab editor and similar tablature editing software

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple just display your notes like that:

```
A    B   C    D   E    F
------------------X----1
X--------3--------------
--------------X---------
------------------------
-----1------------------
------------------------
```

Just create a mapping between a representation of a note and the actual note.